# How to calculate conditional expectation only from the characteristic function

Tags: probability, expectation

I would like to calculate conditional expectation $E[X|A]$, where $A$ is a set, only from the characteristic function $\phi(\omega)$ of a random variable $X$. How can I do this?

Since the characteristic function describes the density function completely, I should be able to do everything at the frequency domain but I dont know how it can be done. If there is no conditioning then, the result is simply the derivative of the characteristic function.

I also wonder how to calculate 
$$\int_{-\infty}^A f(t)\mathrm{d}t$$
from the chracteristic function $\phi(\omega)$ without going back to the density domain.

Thanks alot...

NOTES:

I found a solution to the second part of my question from

$$F_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{iwx}\phi_X(-w)-e^{-iwx}\phi_X(w)}{iw} \mathrm{d}w$$
with $F_X(A)$

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect to do that in some more simple/direct way than the obvious: computing the conditional density antitransforming, etc, as in the deleted answer.

Comment: @leonbloy because I have horrible equations which involve convolution of the density function with itself and the conditional expectation over these density functions. I have serious difficulties to solve those equations and my current idea is to transfer everything to the frequency domain and do the multiplication instead of convolution. If the expectations would be un conditional then I would also take the derivatives then I would be done. I would obtain the equations in a very simple way. That is the reason

Comment: The problem is that conditioning has a simple effect on the density function, not in the frequency domain. I doubt there is nice way here.

Comment: @leonbloy I also dont know, though I have some ideas. On the density function , we just define it in some sub-set of the domain, then scale it to $1$ in this sub domain and calculate the expected value. Cropping on the density domain is not cropping in the frequency domain and scaling ins some known thing in the frequency domain but I dont remember currently, one needs to see fourier transform tables. May be you are right, it might be complicated. But still sounds interesting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional expectation $E[X | A]$ will change depending on whether or not $A$ is independent from $X$. If independent, $E[X | A] = E[X]$, else $E[X | A]$ can have different values on $A$ and $A^c$. For example, if $X = 1_A$, then $E[1_A | A] = 1_A$, but if $B$ is a set independent from $A$, with $P(A) = P(B)$, then $E[1_B | A] = P(B)$ (deterministic). In this case, the distributions defined by $1_A$ and $1_B$ agree, and hence their characteristic functions agree. (Note that the characteristic function of $X$ at $t$ is the integral $\int e^{itx} dP_X$, and in particular depends only on the distribution induced by $X$ on the real line.)

So, since we can find two random variables, whose characteristic funtions agree, but whose conditional expectations (with respect to a particular sigma algebra) are substantially different (inducing different distributions), it is impossible to determine the conditional expectation from the characteristic function alone. (At least, without additional information.)

Does it make sense?